# <at> (the) last moment/night

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, articles

I am confused about using these terms.

1- He came at last night.
2- He came last night.
3- He came at the last night.
4- He came the last night.

1.1- He came at last moment.
1.2- He came last moment.
1.3- He came at the last moment. (Seems ok)
1.4- He came the last moment.

I am confused, because I know #2 is correct but why not #1.2 then? 
And if #1 is correct, why not #1.1 ?
Or tell me if they are already so.

Answer (score 1):

They are different meanings of the word *last*, and they have different grammatical requirements.

With a time period, *last* means "the most recent before now": *last night*, *last week*, *last month*, *last decade*, *last century*. (We don't say *last day*, as there is a separate word: *yesterday*. Shorter times, like *last hour*, are rare to non-existent: I believe I have met *last hour* in an old book, but not in current use).

These expressions are used adverbially, and do not take a preposition (such as *on* or *at*.

The more general meaning of *last* is "the final or most recent in a series"), and in that sense, it does not affect what preposition is used with its head noun.

We say *on a day* so we can say *on the last day [of the holidays]*. The bracketed expression can be omitted, but only when it is already established which period of days we are talking about.

Similarly *in/during the last year [of my study]*

We say *at a moment*, so we say *at the last moment [of the game]*.

There is also an idiom *at the last moment* meaning "at the last possible time for something". But it is always in this form, never *last moment*.

Answer (score 0):

Usually at/on/in is used with time expressions (last,next,any-,every-)
more info 
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time

I think the reason "at the last moment" is different is because of "the" in the phrasing refers to that very specific moment of a certain event. Because "living in the moment" is also a generally accepted form of phrasing.